# Python importing without classes

Tags: python, python-import

So I have a file structure resembling this

```
src
|--- app
   |--- __init__.py
   |--- calc.py
|--- assets
|--- main.py
|--- environment.yml
```

In `__init__.py` I just have

```py
print('Importing app...")
```

and `calc.py` has

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label

class App(Tk):
   def __init__():
      super().__init__()
      Label(self, text='Hello, World!').pack()
```

and finally in `main.py`

```py
import app

print(dir(app))
```

However, `app` only has

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Where is my App class?

Comment: In `app.calc`? Are you perhaps asking why the sub-module `calc` isn't an attribute of its parent module?

Comment: Yes why isn't calc or App in the app module?

Answer (score 0):

> In `__init__.py` I just have
>
> ```
> print('Importing app...")
> ```

So this code will be executed when you `import app`. Thus, `app` won't have an attribute `App` from `calc.py` because the `App` class isn't mentioned in `__init__.py`.

If you change `__init__.py` to look like this:

```
print('Importing app...")

from .calc import App
```

...then `import app; app.App` will work.

---

#### Example

```sh
$ mkdir pymod # setup module structure
$ cd pymod
$ echo "class App: ..." > calc.py
$ echo "from .calc import App" > __init__.py
$ cd .. # get out of the module
$ echo "import pymod; print(dir(pymod))" > test.py # use module
$ python3 test.py # run code
['App', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'calc']
```

As you can see, `App` is now present.

Comment: How is .calc different from app.calc?

Comment: @Thamidu `app.calc` wouldn't make sense in that context because `__init__.py` is within the `app` directory.

Comment: @Thamidu, try it: write `from app.calc import App` in `__init__.py` and observe the error message